# C++ - Method exit

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, and I am trying to write a program which goes from main-method to a case-choice and than to a second method with a if-choice.
But the second `cin` gets skipped and the program exits in the method Lobby after printing out the text.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void Char();
void Lobby();
void Status(); 
void Test(); 

int i;
char c;
char pcharchoice;
int money;  
char pname; 

int main() {
    cout << "$$ Test $$\n";
    Char();
}

void Char(){
    cout << "Select :\n";
    cout << "1 : Test1  \n";
    cout << "2 : Test2  \n";
    cin >> pcharchoice;                
    cout << "\n";

    switch (pcharchoice) {
        case '1':
            money = 1000;
            break;
        case '2':
            money = 2500;
            break;
        default:
            exit(0);
        break;
    }

    cout << "Select a Name:\n";
    cin >> pname;

    Lobby();
}


void Lobby(){

    i = 0; 

    cout << "What would do ? \n";
    cout << "1 : Status \n";
    cout << "2 : Test \n";
    cout << "3 : Leave \n";

    cin >> i;                
    cout << "\n";

    if( i == 1 ) {
        Status();
    } else if( i == 2 ){
        Test();
    } else if ( i == 3 ){
        cout << "Quit\n";   
    }       
}

void Status(){
    cout << "** Status **\n";
    //TODO
}

void Test(){
    cout << "** Test **\n";
    //TODO  
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is skipped. It should have read the newline character.

Comment: Try printing out the value you have in `pcharchoice`

Comment: It was wrong that newline is read, but [couldn't reproduce](http://i.imgur.com/XVUsbPw.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading a character with `std::cin` and the `>>` operator, you read one character. The problem is that you enter *two* characters of input: The actual character, and the newline you use to terminate the current input.

That newline is still in the input buffer, and next character you read will be that newline. This is because reading single characters reads the exact characters that are in the input buffer, it doesn't skip white-space.

There are two simple way of solving this, and two more complicated ways. The first simple way is to not read characters, but *strings* instead, because then the input operator `>>` will skip leading white-space, like for example newlines.

The second simple solution is to use [the `std::skipws` I/O manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), to tell the input stream to skip all white-space:

```
cin >> skipws >> pcharchoice;
```

If you just want characters and don't expect any problems with the user entering to much input, this is the solution I recommend.

The first little more complicated method is to use the [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) function to skip past the newline:

```
cin >> pcharchoice;
cin.ignore((numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This solution has one big advantage in that it skips not only white-space until it passes the end of the line, it also skips any extra input the user might have given on the same line.

The second little more complicated method is to read the whole line into a string, and then get the character from the line (either by using index `0` of the string, or by using `std::istringstream` and "normal" formatted input operators).

Comment: It looks like the problem is deeper: by default formatted input skips whitespaces. It seems that something unsets `skipsw` flag from stream.